# How to get every regex match in an element as range

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I'm making a rich text editor that will convert some regex patterns while the user is writing.
For example `**text**` should be converted to **`<b>text</b>`**.

I found this function for surrounding text selections while keeping the cursor position:

```js
function insertAtSelection(textBefore, textAfter){
  if (window.getSelection){
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0){
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;
      var startTextNode = document.createTextNode(textBefore);
      var endTextNode=document.createTextNode(textAfter);
      var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
      boundaryRange.collapse(false);
      boundaryRange.insertNode(endTextNode);
      boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
      boundaryRange.collapse(true);
      boundaryRange.insertNode(startTextNode);

      // Reselect the original
      range.setStartAfter(startTextNode);
      range.setEndBefore(endTextNode);
      sel.removeAllRanges();sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
}


document.getElementById("insert-btn").addEventListener("click", ()=>{insertAtSelection('<b>', '</b>')})
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>

<button id="insert-btn" >Insert b-tag around selection</button>
```

How can I get an array with all the matches for `/(\*\*((?:.[^\*\*\*\*]|\w))+\*\*)/g` and surround them similar to the above function?

Comment: @MattEllen It should be `range`, not `textrange`. I've updated it

Comment: I don't know the final purpose of your code, but it seems like you want to replicate an existing markup language, `Markdown`. You may be interested in a library like this: [ShowDown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown). It is the first one I have found and it is free, but there will certainly be others.